# How to change the total credits selected live on a webpage with checkbox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, live

Hey my webpage is having a checkbox where students have to select the modules they wish to select. Is it possible that I can update the total module credits selected live on the webpage when the student clicks on a checkbox?  Or when the student clicks submit can I show a message like please select 60 credits?

Answer (score 2):

Create a javascript function that reads the checkboxes and displays the total.  Then set the onclick event of each checkbox to call that method.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jQuery Calculation](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm) plugin. It does exactly what you need.